# Where clause from a subquery

Tags: oracle

I have a table with business days BUSINESS_DAYS which has all the dates

I have another table with payment information and DUE_DATES

I want to return in my query the next business day IF the DUE_DATE is not a business day

```
SELECT SQ1.DUE_DATE, SQ2.DATE FROM 
      (SELECT * FROM
      PAYMENTS
      ORDER BY
      DUE_DATE) SQ1,
      (SELECT MIN(DATE) DATE FROM BUSINESS_DAYS WHERE SQ1.DUE_DATE <= DATE GROUP BY DATE) SQ2
```

Anyone can shed some light?

Comment: You don't say what problem you encounter when you run this code.  My guess is that it runs and you get more rows than you expect because the `group by date` causes `sq2` to return multiple rows rather than a single row.  My guess is that you just want to remove that.  If this your actual code, however, you might be getting a syntax error because `date` is a reserved word so the column probably isn't named `date`.

Comment: Please post some sample data of both the tables.

Comment: You need to describe the problem why this code is considered wrong.

Comment: Please don't use `DATE` as an identifier in your tables or code. It's a datatype name in Oracle.  It's also a pretty undescriptive name.  Maybe it should be called BUSINESS_DAY_DATE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it, code you posted doesn't do what you wanted anyway (otherwise, you won't be asking a question at all). Therefore, I'd suggest another approach:

Altering the session (you don't have to do it; my database speaks Croatian so I'm switching to English; also, setting date format to display day name):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_language = 'english';

Session altered.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy, dy';

Session altered.
```

Two CTEs contain

- business_days: as commented, only this year's July, weekends excluded, there are no holidays)
- payments: two rows, one whose due date is a working day and another whose isn't

Sample data end at line #15, query you might be interested in begins at line #16. Its `CASE` expression check whether `due_date` is one of weekend days; if not, due date to be returned is exactly what it is. Otherwise, another `SELECT` statement returns the first (`MIN`) business day larger than `due_date`.

```
SQL> with
  2  business_days (datum) as
  3    -- for simplicity, only all dates in this year's July,
  4    -- weekends excluded (as they aren't business days), no holidays
  5    (select date '2021-07-01' + level - 1
  6     from dual
  7     where to_char(date '2021-07-01' + level - 1, 'dy')
  8           not in ('sat', 'sun')
  9     connect by level <= 31
 10    ),
 11  payments (id, due_date) as
 12    (select 1, date '2021-07-14' from dual -- Wednesday, business day
 13     union all
 14     select 2, date '2021-07-25' from dual -- Sunday, non-business day
 15    )
 16  select p.id,
 17    p.due_date current_due_date,
 18    --
 19    case when to_char(p.due_date, 'dy') not in ('sat', 'sun') then
 20              p.due_date
 21         else (select min(b.datum)
 22               from business_days b
 23               where b.datum > p.due_date
 24              )
 25    end new_due_date
 26  from payments p
 27  order by id;

        ID CURRENT_DUE_DAT NEW_DUE_DATE
---------- --------------- ---------------
         1 14.07.2021, wed 14.07.2021, wed  --> Wednesday remains "as is"
         2 25.07.2021, sun 26.07.2021, mon  --> Sunday switched to Monday

SQL>
```